# Minecraft Command Block Problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have an alarming and one annoying Minecraft 1.8.8 command that is to summon a item in a chest with another command of `[CanPlaceOn]`. This "`[CanPlaceOn]`" command is a command that allow certain things (blocks) to be placed on certain blocks! So when I am in adventure mode I can place the block that has the NBT tag of `CanPlaceOn` on a certain block. It would be helpful if someone could please provide the command for summoning a button in a chest that has the NBT `CanPlaceOn` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
/blockdata x y z {Items:[0:{id:minecraft:wooden_button,tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stonebrick"]},Count:1}]}
```

Which can *add* to an already filled chest. Replace `x y z` with the coordinates.

---

The `/blockdata` command changes, well, the data of a block (go figure!) Basically, I change the data of a chest to include a wooden button with the tag `CanPlaceOn`. Pretty simple, really.

Comment: Thank you that is correct command because if you reset 2 or more times the chest just breaks

Comment: @Cole Glad I helped! Please consider clicking the green check next to my answer. That shows that I solved your problem, and future visitors can easy find out that this is in fact the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself! If you want to do this type

```
/summon FallingSand ~ ~20 ~ {TileID:54,Time:1,TileEntityData:{Items:[{id:143,Count:1,tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stonebrick"]}}]}}
```

This will summon a chest with a button in it!

Comment: I thought you wanted a put the item in an *already existing* chest, no? That's what my answer does :P

Comment: You should **not** be using the `TileID` tag (which is deprecated), nor numerical IDs. Use `Block` instead of `TileID` (in which you will specify a name ID), and "minecraft:wooden_button" would become the item ID.

Comment: Last I checked, falling sand entities have been falling out of favour (no pun intended), especially for setting a single block.  You can still do interesting things with falling sand, but it isn't as important as it used to be.  I think it's mainly used for single command block contraptions that summon a whole bunch of other command blocks.